# Where can I find Einstein's proof of the existence of atoms?

Tags: atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, education, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

as the question states, where i can i find einstein's proof of the existence of atoms, and also, what math pre-requisites do i need to understand it deeply enough to be able to replicate it.

Comment: Well, the first issue is that what Einstein derived isn't a "proof" in the mathematical sense of the existence of atoms, but rather, a _prediction_ describing the existence and properties of Brownian motion, which relies on the postulate that atoms exist. This prediction was later verified by examining Brownian motion.

Comment: http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/SM/MATH3075/r/Einstein_1905.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The [original paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/andp.19053220806) is written in german and is called *"Über die von der molekularkinetischen Theorie der Wärme geforderte Bewegung von in ruhenden Flüssigkeiten suspendierten Teilchen"*. It was published by Einstein in 1905 in *Annalen der Physik*.

The translation of the title is *"On the movement of small particles suspended in a stationary liquid demanded by the molecular-kinetic theory of heat"*. There is a full english translation of the paper avaiable [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9c1d/91a9f0a37e578ee9a6605b224ad554ec6e86.pdf).

There is also an interesting [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cber_die_von_der_molekularkinetischen_Theorie_der_W%C3%A4rme_geforderte_Bewegung_von_in_ruhenden_Fl%C3%BCssigkeiten_suspendierten_Teilchen) about that paper.

> In 1905, Albert Einstein proved the reality of these molecules and
>   their motions by producing the first statistical physics analysis of
>   Brownian motion. French physicist Jean Perrin used Einstein's
>   results to experimentally determine the mass, and the dimensions, of
>   atoms, thereby conclusively verifying Dalton's atomic theory.
>
> Before this paper, atoms were recognized as a useful concept, but
>   physicists and chemists hotly debated whether atoms were real
>   entities. Einstein's statistical discussion of atomic behavior gave
>   experimentalists a way to count atoms with an ordinary microscope.
>   Wilhelm Ostwald, one of the leaders of the anti-atom school, later
>   told Arnold Sommerfeld that he had been converted to a belief in atoms
>   by Einstein's complete explanation of Brownian motion.
>
> The paper also provided the best way up to that time of estimating
>   Avogadro's Number—the corrected value from Einstein's paper was
>   accurate to one significant figure.

Comment: what pre-requisites do i need to understand it deeply enough to be able to replicate it?

Comment: @Simo stochastic calculus?

Comment: @Simo I think you need thermodynamics, classical mechanics and stochastic.